# Call to undefined method Authentication\Controller\Component\AuthenticationComponent::user()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

i want to show 'logout' option in navbar only when the user gets logged in or else just show Home, Login, and Signup options in the navbar. But it shows this error mentioned in title

in AppController.php

```
   public function beforeRender(EventInterface $event)
  {
    if (is_object($this->Authentication)) {
        if ($this->Authentication->user() !== null) {
            $this->set("userIsLoggedIn", true);
            
        } else {
            $this->set("userIsLoggedIn", false);
            
        }
    }
  }
```

in nav.php file

```
<?php if(isset($userIsLoggedIn) && $userIsLoggedIn): ?>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <?= $this->Html->link(
                'Logout',
                '/users/logout',
                ['class' => 'nav-link','target' => '_self']
            ); ?>
        </li>
 <?php else: ?>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <?= $this->Html->link(
                'Login',
                '/users/login',
                ['class' => 'nav-link','target' => '_self']
            ); ?>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <?= $this->Html->link(
                'Signup',
                '/users/signup',
                ['class' => 'nav-link','target' => '_self']
            ); ?>
        </li>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems like the method `user()` doesn't exist in the `$this->Authentication` class (if that is the line where the error is thrown?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably looking at the wrong docs, specifically at the docs of the deprecated `Auth` component that belongs to the CakePHP core.

You should refer to the docs of the new authentication plugin, which is where its `Authentication` component usage is documented. The method for accessing the user via the `Authentication` component is called `getIdentity`:

```php
$identity = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
```

Furthermore, for your specific use case there is also a view helper that provides a method for checking whether the user is logged in. In your `AppView::initialize()` method (`src/View/AppView.php`) load the helper:

```php
$this->loadHelper('Authentication.Identity');
```

Then you can use its `isLoggedIn` method in your view templates, no further code needed in your controller:

```php
<?php if($this->Identity->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

See also

- **[Authentication Cookbook > Authentication Component > Accessing the logged in user](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authentication-component.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > View Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/view-helper.html)**

Comment: thanks for the help @ndm. i just load the helper then used 'isLoggedIn' method and it's working successfully.